# MS SQL - Select only one row for an ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a changelog with insert / update / delete operations:

```
change_id | object_id | operation
----------+-----------+----------
1         | 1         | insert   
2         | 2         | insert   
3         | 1         | delete   
4         | 1         | insert   
5         | 3         | insert   
6         | 2         | delete
7         | 4         | insert
8         | 3         | update
```

I need to select only the last row for each `object_id` and keep the result sorted by `change_id`. The result should look like this:

```
change_id | object_id | operation
----------+-----------+----------
4         | 1         | insert
6         | 2         | delete
7         | 4         | insert
8         | 3         | update
```

How can I do this? Is it possible with a simple query, without stored procedures?

Comment: Are you *assuming* the highest change_id is the most recent change, or do you have some kind of timestamp column?

Comment: Yes, the highest change_id means the most recent change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68745/1/0):

```
SELECT c.change_id, c.object_id, c.operation 
FROM 
(
  SELECT MAX(change_id) AS CID
  FROM changelog 
  GROUP BY object_id
) s
INNER JOIN changelog c on c.change_id = s.CID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT change_id,
           object_id,
           operation,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY object_id ORDER BY change_id DESC) AS rn
    FROM   ChangeLog
)
SELECT change_id,
       object_id,
       operation
FROM   MyCTE 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e5b87/2)**

Answer (score 1):

Using Ranking functions [SQL Server Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx):

```
SELECT change_id, object_id, operation
FROM
   ( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY object_id ORDER BY change_id DESC) as rownum,
        change_id, object_id, operation
    FROM yourtable
   )a
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The notion of "last" is easy to establish if you add a timestamp column (e.g. LAST_UPDATE) that captures when the operation occurred.  You would SELECT the row WHERE the LAST_UPDATE is the max value